# Getting "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Forked Java VM exited abnormally" Exception

Tags: java, junit, netbeans-6.9

I have a java program for JUnit test which I have written in netbeans IDE where I am testing a class with single thread.
When I am going to compile this its working fine and showing results 100% success, but 
when I am trying to run this program I am getting an exception that is -

> Testsuite: glb.chatmeter.crawler.yahoolocal.YahooBusinessDataTest
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.057 sec
>
> Testcase: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1):        FAILED
>   No tests found in glb.chatmeter.crawler.yahoolocal.YahooBusinessDataTest
>   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in glb.chatmeter.crawler.yahoolocal.YahooBusinessDataTest
>
> Testsuite: glb.chatmeter.crawler.yahoolocal.YahooBusinessDataTest
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
>
> Testcase: glb.chatmeter.crawler.yahoolocal.YahooBusinessDataTest:null:        Caused an ERROR
>   Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
>   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
>           at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)

is its netbean problem or some thing else? is any one help me thanks.

My code is like this-

```
public class BusinessDataTest {

    String url = "http://local.com/info-66122628-andy-richards-house-painting-mesa";
    Integer[] locId = {1354};
    String customerDetail ="Business Name";

    public BusinessDataTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetFullDataOfBusiness() {
        System.out.println("getFullDataOfBusiness");
        BusinessData instance = new BusinessData();
        Integer expResult = 4;
        Integer result = instance.getFullDataOfBusiness(url, customerDetail);
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you placed any code calling exit or shutdown in your test suite?

Comment: Is it JUnit4 or JUnit3? If JUnit4, make sure you're *not* inheriting from TestCase and that you *are* using the `@Test` annotation.

Comment: @ Alexander : No, not calling exit or shutdown.

Comment: @Ben Using JUnit4
and not inheriting TestCase

Comment: @KhoyendraPande: Have you verified that it's not inheriting from TestCase, that it is using the `@Test` annotation, and that it's not using the `@Ignore` annotation? I realize these might seem obvious, but sometimes those are the things easiest to miss.

Comment: @BenHocking : Yeah not inheriting TestCase

Comment: Posting some code would definitely help us too help you.

Comment: @Perception : I have added my code, plz check. Thx

Comment: The error tell about YahooBusinessDataTest. Your code pasted above does not have 'yahoo'. Are you sure   you are running the correct test?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Netbeans - See [Bug 204729](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204729)